# Running of GCD queue on a thread

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am creating a GCD queue using 
dispatch_queue_t q1 = dispatch_queue_create("com.s1", NULL);

and dispatching a block on it using dispatch_async

Does GCD make any guarantees on what thread it is run on? I notice that it is always executed on a background thread. Is there a chance it can be executed on the main/UI thread. How does GCD decide what thread to run on?

Comment: It's doing what you said. If you wanted the main queue, why didn't you ask for the main queue? You asked for a new queue, you got one. Obviously the new queue is not the main queue; the main queue already exists, so it can't be the new queue you just created.

Comment: Consider reading the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW1

Answer (score 8):

Threads are not queues, and vice versa.

When you dispatch blocks to a GCD queue, GCD ensures that they run according to the rules of that queue-- serially or concurrently, depending on how you create the queue. It **does not guarantee what thread(s) it will use.** It decides how to run things according to its own internal logic. There's also no guarantee that a given serial queue will always use the same thread.

The only exception is the main queue, obtained by calling `dispatch_get_main_queue`. That's a serial queue that runs on the main thread.

If you create your own queue, blocks that run on it will not be running on the main thread/queue. What thread they *do* run on is up to GCD.